# Adding timezone and datetime columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timezone

Is a for-loop the most efficient way to achieve the following? It appears to be working but takes a long time on 3 million rows (about 6 seconds to update 100 rows, using tz_localize, or roughly five hours!).

```py
whois_timezone_info = { "A": 1 * 3600, "ACDT": 10 * 3600, ..., "CDT": -5 * 3600, ..., "EST": -5 * 3600, ...}

df = pd.DataFrame({
  't': ['2001-06-01T00:00:00', '2001-06-01T00:00:00'],
  'z': ['CDT', 'EST']
})

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t'])

# Doesn't work, as .tz_localize expects a string
df['datetime-z'] = df['datetime'].dt.tz_localize(df['t'])

# Works... But very slow on large DataFrames (e.g. 3 million rows)
for idx, i in df.iterrows(): # int, [] values
  df.loc[idx, 'datetime-z'] = i['datetime'].tz_localize(
    tz=whois_timezone_info[i['t']]
  )
```

Comment: one idea is to apply the operation in groups - `df['dt_aware'] = pd.concat( [y['datetime'].dt.tz_localize(y) for x,y in df.groupby('z')])`

Comment: `import pytz; print(pytz.all_timezones)` if you need to check -

Comment: `tz_localize(x)` and yes this works

Comment: Ah my bad it errored for me, did it run quickly?

Comment: @Umar.H Yes quickly enough around 45 seconds for 3m. rows

Comment: consider mapping time zone abbreviations to [IANA time zone names](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), e.g. `{"EST": "America/New_York"}` so that DST is accounted for if you do timedelta arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

This iterates through all timezone groupings to add the datetime+timezone column. (And coincidentally is much more efficient as it takes 20 seconds on the 3-million row dataset.)

```py
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t'])
for i in df['z'].value_counts().index.to_list():
  df.loc[df['z'] == i, 'datetime-z'] = df.loc[df['z'] == i, 'datetime'].dt.tz_localize(
    whois_timezone_info[i]
  )
```

Comment: @MrFuppes At the time that the previous post was downvoted, it had a different solution, which I later found to be erroneous. I then hid the answer. When I found a new solution, I changed that answer, but then thought it more prudent to add it as a different answer. Perhaps the history can attest to this, perhaps not? Regarding "20 seconds", the original question itself is in regard to efficiency and hence clearly states a time for completion using a specific (3-million row) dataset, i.e. "...roughly five hours!" Nonetheless, it is a bit vague... so I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification. That's why I commented the downvote, happy to remove it. People often don't come back, so improved answers stay discredited...

Comment: Regarding the question, I think for questions about the efficiency of certain methods it is helpful to add relative comparisons. That is, A vs. B vs. etc. based on synthetic data for reproducibility. You can illustrate that e.g. with [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) or other tools such as [simple_benchmark](https://pypi.org/project/simple-benchmark/).